# Organize code using MongoDb with Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I had a Node.js application that do web scraping and save some information in a json object.
I have also saved this object to file.

Now I want to save these information to a MongoDB database.

This is the structure of my code:

**app.js** file:

```
var express = require('express');

// my files
var downloaderFirst = require('./routers/downloaderFirst.js');
var downloaderSecond = require('./routers/downloaderSecond.js');

// create app
const app = express();

downloaderFirst.download();
downloaderSecond.download();
```

**./routers/downloaderFirst.js** file:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var textract = require('textract');

// object of methods
var methods = {};

var url = 'http://www....';

// json object containing data
var jsons = [];

methods.download = function(req, res) {
    extractText();
};

function extractText() {
    // get text and save it to jsons array and ./output/dataFirst.json file
    var thisYear = ...;
    var thisObject = ...;
    var o = {year: thisYear, object: thisObject};
    jsons.push(o);
    printOnFile(jsons, './output/dataFirst.json');
}

module.exports = methods;
```

**./routers/downloaderSecondt.js** file:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var textract = require('textract');

// object of methods
var methods = {};

var url = 'http://www....';

// json object containing data
var jsons = [];

methods.download = function(req, res) {
    extractText();
};

function extractText() {
    // get text and save it to jsons array and ./output/dataSecond.json file
    var thisYear = ...;
    var thisColor = ...;
    var o = {year: thisYear, color: thisColor};
    jsons.push(o);
    printOnFile(jsons, './output/dataFirst.json');
}

module.exports = methods;
```

So now I have two files (`dataFirst.json` and `dataSecond.json`) containing an object like:

**dataFirst.json** file:

```
[{
    "year": "2006",
    "object": "car"
},
{
    "year": "2002",
    "object": "car"
},
{
    "year": "2006",
    "object": "pen"
}, ...];
```

**dataSecond.json** file:

```
[{
    "year": "2006",
    "color": "red"
},
{
    "year": "2002",
    "color": "blue"
},
{
    "year": "2006",
    "color": "yellow"
}, ...];
```

I want to save these information to MongoDB using two different collection called `first` and `second`.
I think I can do two things:

1. get these documents from files and save them all togheter
2. save a document at time. So, instead of create `dataFirst.json` and `dataSecond.json`, save the documnt directly to the right collection of the database.

Obviously I installed MongoDb drivers using `npm install mongodb --save` command.

Anyway, I want a function to connect (and create if not exists) to db, and insert documents.

So I create **./data/db.js** file:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';

// object of methods
var methods = {};

methods.createDb = function(dbName) {
    MongoClient.connect(url + dbName, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log('Database created!');
        db.close();
    });
}

methods.createCollection = function(dbName, collectionName) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        var dbo = db.db(dbName);
        dbo.createCollection(collectionName, function(err, res) {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log('Collection', collectionName, 'created!');
            db.close();
        });
    });
}

methods.insertDoc = function(dbName, collectionName, doc) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        var dbo = db.db(dbName);
        dbo.collection(collectionName).insertOne(doc, function(err, res) {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log('1 document inserted');
            db.close();
        });
    });
}

methods.insertManyDoc = function(dbName, collectionName, docs) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        var dbo = db.db(dbName);
        dbo.collection(collectionName).insertMany(docs, function(err, res) {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log('Number of documents inserted: ' + res.insertedCount);
            db.close();
        });
    });
}

methods.insertFromFile = function(dbName, collectionName, filename) {
    var objs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8'));
    this.insertManyDoc(dbName, collectionName, objs);
}

module.exports = methods;
```

For solution (1), I modify my **app.js** file:

```
var express = require('express');

// my files
var downloaderFirst = require('./routers/downloaderFirst.js');
var downloaderSecond = require('./routers/downloaderSecond.js');

var db = require('./data/db.js');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// create app
const app = express();

downloaderFirst.download();
downloaderSecond.download();

var dbName = 'db';
var firstCollectionName = 'first';
var secondCollectionName = 'second';

// create database
db.createDb(dbName);
// create the collections (tables in SQL)
db.createCollection(dbName, firstCollectionName);
db.createCollection(dbName, secondCollectionName);

db.insertFromFile(dbName, firstCollectionName, './output/dataFirst.json');
db.findAll(dbName, firstCollectionName);
```

The problem is that if I run the project two times, then the collection has doplicate documents, because the insert function doesn't test if the element exists yet or not.

For solution (2) I modify **app.js** and **./routers/downloaderFirst.js**.

**app.js** file:

```
var express = require('express');

// my files
var downloaderFirst = require('./routers/downloaderFirst.js');
var downloaderSecond = require('./routers/downloaderSecond.js');

var db = require('./data/db.js');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// create app
const app = express();

downloaderFirst.download();
downloaderSecond.download();

var dbName = 'db';
var firstCollectionName = 'first';
var secondCollectionName = 'second';

// create database
db.createDb(dbName);
// create the collections (tables in SQL)
db.createCollection(dbName, firstCollectionName);
db.createCollection(dbName, secondCollectionName);
```

**./routers/downloaderFirst.js** file:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var textract = require('textract');
var db = require('../data/db.js');

// object of methods
var methods = {};

var url = 'http://www....';

// json object containing data
var jsons = [];

methods.download = function(req, res) {
    extractText();
};

function extractText() {
    // get text and save it to jsons array and ./output/dataFirst.json file
    var thisYear = ...;
    var thisObject = ...;
    var o = {year: thisYear, object: thisObject};
    jsons.push(o);
    printOnFile(jsons, './output/dataFirst.json');
    db.insertDoc('db', 'first', obj);
}

module.exports = methods;
```

In this case, I have the same problem (duplicate documents) and then I get this error:

> Database created! Collection first created! Collection second
>   created! Number of documents inserted: 10692
>
> C:...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:792
>             throw err;
>             ^ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNe tworkError: connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
>       at Pool. (C:...\node_modules\mongodb-core \lib\topologies\server.js:503:11)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at Connection. (C:...\node_modules\mongod b-core\lib\connection\pool.js:326:12)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>       at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
>       at Socket. (C:...\node_modules\mongodb-co re\lib\connection\connection.js:245:50)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)

Anyway, how can I modify my code so to eliminate the duplication problem?
Is good to connect and close connection each time?
How can I improve my code? I mean organize better the code.

I read a lot of tutorial but I can't solve my problems.
Sorry, if it is a stupid thing but it's the first time I use Node.js, MongoDb and it's also the first time I do web scraping, so now I'm very confused.

Thanks!

---

## EDIT 1

I modify the code in this way:

**app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');

// my files
var downloaderFirst = require('./routers/downloaderFirst.js');
var downloaderSecond = require('./routers/downloaderSecond.js');

var db = require('./data/db.js');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// create app
const app = express();

var dbName = 'db';

// create database
db.createDb(dbName);

downloaderFirst.download();
downloaderSecond.download();

db.disconnectDb(dbName);
```

**./routers/downloaderFirst.js** file:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var textract = require('textract');
var db = require('../data/db.js');

// object of methods
var methods = {};

var url = 'http://www....';

// json object containing data
var jsons = [];

methods.download = function(req, res) {
    extractText();
};

function extractText() {
    // get text and save it to jsons array and ./output/dataFirst.json file
    var thisYear = ...;
    var thisObject = ...;
    var o = {year: thisYear, object: thisObject};
    jsons.push(o);
    printOnFile(jsons, './output/dataFirst.json');
    db.insertDocFirst('db', 'first', obj);
}

module.exports = methods;
```

Where **db.js** is:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';

// object of methods
var methods = {};

methods.createDb = function(dbName) {
    MongoClient.connect(url + dbName, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('createDb', err);
            //throw err;
        }
        console.log('Database created!');
        var dbo = db.db(dbName);
        var first = dbo.createCollection('first', function(err, res) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('create collection first', err);
                //throw err;
            }
            console.log('Collection first created!');
            /*// because we are searching by name, we need an index! without an index, things can get slow
            first.ensureIndex({year: true, object: true}, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    throw err;
                }
            });
            console.log('Index of collection first created!');*/
        });
        var second = dbo.createCollection('second', function(err, res) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('create collection second', err);
                //throw err;
            }
            console.log('Collection second created!');
            /*// because we are searching by name, we need an index! without an index, things can get slow
            dbo.collection('second').createIndex({year: true, color: true}, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log('ensureIndex second', err);
                    //throw err;
                }
            });
            console.log('Index of collection second created!');*/
        });
    });
}

methods.disconnectDb = function(dbName) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('disconnectDb', err)
            //throw err;
        }
        console.log('Disconnected. Bye :)');
        db.close();
    });
}

methods.insertDocFirst = function(dbName, collectionName, doc) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('insertDoc', err); // ** ERROR HERE **
            //throw err;
        }
        var dbo = db.db(dbName);
        var selector = {
            "year": doc.year,
            "color": doc.color
        };
        dbo.collection(collectionName).update(selector, doc, {upsert: true});
    });
}

methods.insertDocSecond = function(dbName, collectionName, doc) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('insertDoc', err);
            //throw err;
        }
        var dbo = db.db(dbName);
        var selector = {
            "year": doc.year,
            "object": doc.color
        };
        dbo.collection(collectionName).update(selector, doc, {upsert: true});
    });
}
```

When I run the code, I get:

```
Disconnected. Bye :)
Database created!
insertDoc { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first conn
ect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\mongodb-core
\lib\topologies\server.js:503:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\mongod
b-core\lib\connection\pool.js:326:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\mongodb-co
re\lib\connection\connection.js:245:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkEr
ror: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]' }
C:\...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:792
          throw err;
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of null
    at C:\...\data\db.js:105:16
    at err (C:\...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:414:
14)
    at executeCallback (C:\...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\u
tils.js:403:25)
    at C:\Users\...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:27
0:21
    at connectCallback (C:\...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\m
ongo_client.js:940:5)
    at C:\...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:78
9:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Obviously I before start MongoDb in this way:

```
mongod -dbpath C:\...\data
```

What is the problem?

---

## EDIT 2

Thanks a lot for your help.
I'm trying to modify the cose adding the creation of collections.

This is now my code.

**app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');

// my files
var downloaderFirst = require('./routers/downloaderFirst.js');
var downloaderSecond = require('./routers/downloaderSecond.js');

var db = require('./data/db.js');

// create app
const app = express();

downloaderFirst.download();
downloaderSecond.download();
```

**db.js**:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
let dbInstance;

// object of methods
var methods = {};

const connectDb = function(dbName, cb) {
    if(dbInstance) {
        return cb(dbInstance);
    }
    else {
        MongoClient.connect(url + dbName, function(err, db) {
            if(!err) {
                dbInstance = db;
                return cb(db);
            }
        });
    }
}

methods.insertFirst = function(dbName, collectionName, doc) {
    connectDb(dbName, function(db) {
        var dbo = db.db(dbName);
        var selector = {
            year: doc.year,
            color: doc.color
        };
        dbo.collection(collectionName).update(selector, doc, {upsert: true});
    });
}

methods.insertSecond = function(dbName, collectionName, doc) {
    connectDb(dbName, function(db) {
        var dbo = db.db(dbName);
        var selector = {
            year: doc.year,
            object: doc.object
        };
        dbo.collection(collectionName).update(selector, doc, {upsert: true});
    });
}
```

**./routers/downloaderFirst.js**:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var textract = require('textract');
var db = require('../data/db.js');

// object of methods
var methods = {};

var url = 'http://www....';

// json object containing data
var jsons = [];

methods.download = function(req, res) {
    extractText();
};

function extractText() {
    // get text and save it to jsons array and ./output/dataFirst.json file
    var thisYear = ...;
    var thisObject = ...;
    var o = {year: thisYear, object: thisObject};
    jsons.push(o);
    printOnFile(jsons, './output/dataFirst.json');
    db.insertFirst('db', 'first', obj);
}

module.exports = methods;
```

When I run, I get:

```
(node:5708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1
): MongoError: BSON field 'update.updates.q' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'obj
ect'
(node:5708) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process wit
h a non-zero exit code.
(node:5708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2
): MongoError: BSON field 'update.updates.q' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'obj
ect'
(node:5708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3
): MongoError: BSON field 'update.updates.q' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'obj
ect'
^C
```

Then I can use Compass to analyse my db.
I see that collections are created, but there aren't all the documents that should be there.
Should be there 10692 documents in 'second' collection and 16102 documents in 'first' collection but there are 2398 documents in 'second' collection and 933 documents in 'first' collection.

And then, I thought about how (and when) call db.close().
The problem is that my app should do web scraping, save information on db an visualize data using d3.js. 
Now I would like to put db.close() when the app finish to save all the information on db.

If node was synchronous, I will would made something like that:

**app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');

// my files
var downloaderFirst = require('./routers/downloaderFirst.js');
var downloaderSecond = require('./routers/downloaderSecond.js');

var db = require('./data/db.js');

// create app
const app = express();

// web scraping and saving on db
downloaderFirst.download();
downloaderSecond.download();

// close connection
db.disconnectDb();
```

where disconnectDb() is in **db.js**:

```
methods.disconnectDb = function(dbName) {
    connectDb(dbName, function(db) {
        var dbo = db.db(dbName);
        db.close();
    });
}
```

But this couldn't work.
So, any tips? It's the very first time I use Node and Mongo, I read a lot but I can't find complete (and not very very simple) examples that shows how to build an app different from "Hello World!".

Thanks

Comment: why you are connecting and disconnecting in each operation ?? connect one time and do the operation till the application is working. when your application is stopped like forcefully by `OS` or by `you` then just close the connection. I think this will solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJs has asynchronous nature. It has single thread event-driven Architecture setup. So, when you are connecting and disconnecting a database connection at each function call, may be some other resource or function is trying to do the same operation.

**Example** - `function A` has created a `mongodb` connection and there is some other function which is also trying to do the same. So this error occurs like what ever you are facing.

**Solution** - Maintain a file where you connect database at the time of app start. when your complete application is going to stop or you are sure about the termination of your application then just disconnect the database connection. This way there will be no `race-around` conditions on `open` and `close`.

**EDITED - 1**

I am adding few more lines based on your edited code.

1. The `app.js` file has following lines

   ```
   1. db.createDb(dbName); //this is an asynchronous operation

   2. downloaderFirst.download(); //this is a route (asynchronous) as per your code base
   3. downloaderSecond.download(); //this is a route (asynchronous) as per your code base

   4. db.disconnectDb(dbName); // this is an asynchronous operation too
   ```

Now line no. 4 is not going to wait to execute for line number 1,2,3 because of Nodejs event-driven architecture. So when you run this code `MongoDB` is `connected` and `disconnected` at the same time independently of each other based on `event-loop`.

2. The `downloaderFirst.js` has this function

   ```
   function extractText() {
       var thisYear = ...;
       var thisObject = ...;
       var o = {year: thisYear, object: thisObject};
       jsons.push(o);
       printOnFile(jsons, './output/dataFirst.json');
       db.insertDocFirst('db', 'first', obj); /*********HERE*****/
   }
   ```

   Please see the `HERE` marked line. This one is again asynchronous and does not wait for `MongoDb` connect . If the `extractText` function is called it starts to execute.
3. The `db.js` file has few problems.

Here you are connecting the database on each operation, which has downsides of multiple connection request at the same time. So it can be done like this way.

Create one function called `connectDb`. which returns the connected `db` instance.Then use it for other database operations like this way.

```
let dbInstance;
const connectDb = function(dbName,cb){
    if(dbInstance){
         return cb(dbInstance);
    }else{
        MongoClient.connect(url + dbName,function(err,db){
              if(!err){
                 dbInstance = db;
                 return cb(db);
              }
        })

    }
 }
```

So use this function to connect `MongoDB`. And write other operations like this.

```
methods.insertDocSecond = function(dbName, collectionName, doc) {
    connectDb(dbName,function(db){
        var dbo = db.db(dbName);
        var selector = {
            "year": doc.year,
            "object": doc.color
        };
        dbo.collection(collectionName).update(selector, doc, {upsert: true}); 
    })
}
```

This way we can ensure that database is connected one time only and rest of the times its passing the reference only.

And last but not the least please make sure to call `close` connection in a proper way so it does not get called asynchronously when some other function is busy in doing some database operation.

**EDITED-2**

`Update` function returns promise and callback both. For your current scenario, your `update` operation is returning some error which is not handled. Use callback function to grab the error properly and see where it is breaking.

Anyways I found you have some understanding issue on how to work with `Nodejs` and `MongoDB`, rather than you are stuck into a problem which is StackOverflow is for.So I must advise you to go through some online material, resources to find out how to work with Nodejs and MongoDB together and then if you are stuck into any particular problem, the community will be happy to help you.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I modified the code removing `db.close()` but I have always errors. Can you please help me?

Comment: you can edit the question with the updated code so that community can have a look on the issue @doubt

Comment: Is what I did :)

Comment: I edited again my main message, I would be very pleased if you helped me..